# .htaccess to nginx rewrite rules excluding certain folders

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

So im trying to move an application from apache to NginX but I've discovered i need to re write the .htaccess file, I've had a good look around but finally I need to ask for some help.

Below is the .htaccess file from apache, im trying to redirect all requests to index.php except for requests to /html, /css, /images, /php.

Thanks for your help in advance!
Bill

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^html [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^css [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^images [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !directory/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So far I have the below and the requests for the html, css, images and php files are working great.

But when i make a request for www.domain.com/blah/blah/blah/ im getting a 404, what i really want is for the URL to reamin as www.domain.com/blah/blah/blah/ but load the index.php file

```
location ~ directory/(.*)$ {
}

location ~ (.*)$ {
}

location /html {
rewrite ^/html / break;
}

location /css {
rewrite ^/css / break;
}

location /images {
rewrite ^/images / break;
}

location /php {
rewrite ^/php / break;
}

location / {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 redirect;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines for filtering requests to content in specific folders:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if not requesting content in one of the specified folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(html|css|images|php)/ [NC]
# redirect visitor to the index page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

The exclamation mark ( ! ) before the rewrite condition means a negation, so if the requested filename DOES NOT start with html or css or ...., apply the rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks Tom, using the converter ive seen while researching it gives me..

`code`
    if ($request_filename !~* "^(html|css|images|php)/"){
     set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }
    if ($rule_0 = "1"){
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
    }`code`